# Storing Pointer to sqlite3 Database inside class throws segfault

Tags: c++, sqlite, class

In my program, I am using a sqlite3 database.

In order to handle the Ctrl-C signal and gracefully terminate the program by closing the database and closing all Midi ports (my program uses RtMidi), I need to set up a global object that stores them. I have made a class:

```
class Config {
private:
    sqlite3 *Database;
    RtMidiIn *MidiIn;
    RtMidiOut *MidiOut;

public:     
    sqlite3 *getDatabase();
    void setDatabase(sqlite3 *mDatabase);

    RtMidiIn *getMidiInStream();
    void setMidiInStream(RtMidiIn *mMidiIn);

    RtMidiOut *getMidiOutStream();
    void setMidiOutStream(RtMidiOut *mMidiOut);

    Config();
    ~Config();
};
```

The constructor:

```
Config::Config() {
    //open the midi i/o ports (irrelevant to the problem at hand)
    sqlite3 *mDatabase = this->Database;
    if (sqlite3_open(FILE_DATABASE, &mDatabase)) {
        puts(ERROR_MESSAGE_DATABASE_OPEN_FAIL);
        puts(sqlite3_errmsg(this->Database));
    }
    puts(NOTE_MESSAGE_DATABASE_OPEN);
}
```

However, the `sqlite3_open()` and `sqlite3_close()` functions are giving me segfaults when i try to call them on `mConfig->getDatabase()`.

I tried making the fields public and passing `mConfig->Database` and that changes nothing. How can I store the database inside the Config class?

--------EDIT:
I forgot to include the get/set database functions:

```
sqlite3 *Config::getDatabase() { return this->Database; }

void Config::setDatabase(sqlite3 *mDatabase) { this->Database = mDatabase; }
```

Comment: I don't see `getDatabase()`

Comment: @SombreroChicken i edited my question. i forgot to include those functions. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly erroneous:

```
sqlite3 *mDatabase = this->Database;
if (sqlite3_open(FILE_DATABASE, &mDatabase)) {
```

the `sqlite_open` call modifies the local `mDatabase`, but `Config::Database` remains unmodified.

Recommendations:

- initialize POD types. in modern C++, this is as trivial as `sqlite3 *Database = nullptr;`
- consider wrapping the database pointer (and any other managed ressource) into a helper class that is repsonsible for only managing this ressource. One possible solution would be a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter.